# Extending base wicket html without <wicket:child /> tag

Tags: java, wicket

Is it possible to extend existing wicket (= append additional property/textbox in existing wicket html) if the base wicket doesn't contain `<wicket:child/>` tag?

For example, I want to extend some java class which uses the following html:

```
<wicket:panel>
  <div class="field-wrapper"><input wicket:id="field1" type="text"/></div>
  [I WANT TO INJECT ANOTHER TEXTBOX HERE]
</wicket:panel>
```

My extended class inherits all base properties from inherited class, and I declared an additional property. But I don't know if/how I can append the additional property in base html, without having to clone the whole original html and adding my new propery, which is not elegant solution.

Is there any event I can attach to where I can modify original html (inject my property) before it is parsed / rendered?

Answer (score 2):

You can override `#getMarkup()` method and modify its result but it would be more hack-ier than just providing a complete .html file with your modifications.

Providing your own markup file is totally elegant for me!

Comment: providing own markup is not really in accordance with "inheritance principle" where you want to use the original base code and just include some additional properties (like in java classes). However if original markup was intended to be inherited it should contain <wicket:child/> in the first place, otherwise I agree with you that any "code injection" is probably more hack-ish than providing own full markup. I thought that maybe I could override some function where I would be able to modify markup easier with some kind of DOM.

Comment: Such method is onComponentBody(), but it works with MarkupStream and it is not convenient AS working with DOM. You can also use IComponentMarkupProvider but again my opinion is that providing MyPanel.html would be both easier and more maintenanble

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to define a method in your base page that returns a Fragment which will be inserted into the 'childContent' below:

```
<wicket:panel>
  <div class="field-wrapper"><input wicket:id="field1" type="text"/></div>
  <div wicket:id="childContent"></div>
</wicket:panel>
```

So in your base page you would have this function that by default returns null, but extending pages can override it to provide their own specific content:

```
protected Fragment getChildContent() { return null; }
```

And your base page will use it as follow:

```
Fragment childContent = getChildContent();
        if(childContent != null) {
            addOrReplace(childContent);
        } else {
            addOrReplace(new WebComponent("childContent").setVisible(false));
        }
```

Than in your extending page you can define a Fragment with it's own html and override the getChildContent() method to return it.
Hope that helps!